# Make level the printed symbols in the ouput

Tags: ruby, formatting, scite

Consider this Ruby code:

```
puts "*****"
puts "    *"
puts "     "
puts "*****"
puts "       *"
```

My Output is like this:

```
*****  
  *

*****
    *
```

Why the heck a whitespace doesn't fill the same space as ***** character in **Scite**?
I've tried it in Eclypse with Java and it works just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Proportional fonts have characters of varying widths, ruining space-based alignment.

Switch to a monospace font (e.g., Courier) so all characters are the same size and it'll work.

Comment: Right Monospace Font fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work in Scite You should add 
`style.errorlist.32=$(font.monospace)` in 
`SciteUser.properties` file